# Name for a class of almost symplectic manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, terminology, cartan-geometry

A $2n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is said to be *almost symplectic* if it possesses a non-degenerate two-form $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$.  Equivalently, an almost symplectic structure is a $G$-subbundle $P \subset F(M)$ of the frame bundle where $G < GL(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to the symplectic group $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$.

The intrinsic torsion of such a $G$-structure is captured by the three-form $d\omega \in \Omega^3(M)$.  The bundle $\wedge^3 T^*M$ breaks up into the Whitney sum of two $G$-stable sub-bundles corresponding to the $\omega$-traceless 3-forms and their $\omega$-perpendicular complement.  This therefore gives rise to four types of almost symplectic manifolds:

- **symplectic**, where $d\omega = 0$
- **locally conformal symplectic**, where $d\omega = \omega \wedge \varphi$ for some one-form $\varphi$ which is closed and hence $\varphi = df$ locally, allowing us to construct a local symplectic form $e^{-f}\omega$.
- **name?**, where the volume form $\omega^n$ is left invariant by the *hamiltonian vector fields*  $X_f = \omega^\sharp(df)$
- **generic**, where $d\omega$ is none of the above.

My question is whether there is an accepted name for the third type.  I would also appreciate a link to where this classification was made explicit for the first time.

Thank you.

**Edit**  As Robert Bryant pointed out below, the condition **name?** is actually $d\omega^{n-1} = 0$.  I will leave the question unmodified, except for this.

Comment: Hi Jose! I thought this classification appeared for the first time in Gray and Hervella's paper on almost-Hermitian manifolds, section 8. Do you believe there is an earlier source?

Comment: Hi Paul!  That's embarrassing... I studied that paper a long time ago, but all I remembered from it were the almost hermitian classes.  I totally forgot that they also discussed almost symplectic.  Thanks for reminding me!  I'd still like to know if there is an accepted name for the third class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question, because I believe that, if one defines an $\omega$-Hamiltonian vector field to be a vector field of the form $X_f = \omega^\#(\mathrm{d}f)$ where $f$ is a (smooth) function on $M$, then $\omega^{n}$ is *always* invariant under the flow of $X_f$.

To see this, recall that, when $n>1$, if $\omega$ is a non-degenerate $2$-form on $M^{2n}$, its exterior derivative can be written uniquely in the form
$$
\mathrm{d}\omega = \phi\wedge\omega + \psi
$$
where $\phi$ is a $1$-form and $\psi\in\Omega^3(M)$ is *$\omega$-primitive*, i.e., $\omega^{n-2}\wedge\psi = 0$.

Meanwhile, by Cartan's formula for the Lie derivative with respect to $X_f$, we have, since $\iota(X_f)\omega = -\mathrm{d}f $ (where $\iota(X)$ denotes interior product with $X$),
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{X_f}\omega^n &= n\,\omega^{n-1}\wedge \mathcal{L}_{X_f}\omega
= n\,\omega^{n-1}\wedge\bigl(\iota(X_f)(\mathrm{d}\omega) + \mathrm{d}(\iota(X_f)\omega)\bigr)\\
&=n\,\omega^{n-1}\wedge\bigl(\iota(X_f)(\phi\wedge\omega + \psi) + \mathrm{d}(-\mathrm{d}f))\bigr)\\
&=n\,\omega^{n-1}\wedge\bigl(\phi(X_f)\wedge\omega + \phi\wedge\mathrm{d}f+ \iota(X_f)\,\psi)\bigr)\\
&= n\,\omega^{n-1}\wedge\bigl(\iota(X_f)\,\psi\bigr)  =0
\end{align}
$$
since $\omega^{n-2}\wedge\psi=0$ implies

$$
0 = \iota(X_f)(\omega^{n-1}\wedge\psi) = (n{-}1)\,\omega^{n-2}\wedge(-\mathrm{d}f)\wedge\psi + \omega^{n-1}\wedge\bigl(\iota(X_f)\,\psi\bigr).
$$

Instead of the 'Hamiltonian flow invariance' criterion you propose for **name?** (by which, I think, you are trying to capture the condition $\phi=0$), you should instead just require that $\omega^{n-1}$ be *closed*.  (This condition is sometimes known as 'balanced' in the literature.)

By the way, your second type "locally conformally symplectic" is only apt if $n>2$.  When $n=2$, you do *not* automatically get that $\phi$ is closed from the condition $\mathrm{d}\omega = \phi\wedge\omega$.  (In fact, it is generically not true, even though $\psi$ does vanish identically when $n=2$.)

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  Indeed, my calculation had shown that the condition of vanishing $\psi$ was $d\omega \wedge \omega^{n-2} = 0$, which is closure of $\omega^{n-1}$.  For some reason I wedged with $df$ and then interpreted it as $X_f$ preserving the volume form, but did not realise that this was always true.  Thanks a lot!  Also for the name.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill:  I think you meant 'condition of vanishing $\phi$'  (not $\psi$) in your comment.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  I meant to write $\varphi$ as in my calculation.